# winapi strange characters const char*

Tags: visual-studio, winapi, configuration, character-encoding

I'm working on a WinAPI project on Visual Studio 2015 and when i initialize this array:

```
const char* Filtros[] = {
        "Media", "Media Ponderada", "Mediana", "Gaussiano",
        "Ecualización Simple", "Ecualización Unif.", "Suavizado Conservador", "Laplasiano"
    };
```

and bind it to a listbox:

```
CreateWindow(TEXT("COMBOBOX"), TEXT(""),
    CBS_DROPDOWNLIST | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,
    CB_x, CB_y, CB_width, CB_heigth,
    hwnd, (HMENU)CB_FILTROS, NULL, NULL);

for (int i = 0; i < nFiltros; i++) {
    SendDlgItemMessage(hwnd, CB_FILTROS, CB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)Filtros[i]);
}
SendDlgItemMessage(hwnd, CB_FILTROS, CB_SETCURSEL, (WPARAM)3, (LPARAM)0);
```

I get these strange characters:

[image: Strange chracters]

In my ***Proyect Property*** on ***Character Set*** the option that I have selected is ***Use Unicode Character Set***.

I think this must have a really simple solution. I'll be glad for any direction.

Comment: You selected Unicode character set but supply ANSI text. Choose one and stick to it. Also this has been asked hundreds of times. Did you do any research?

Comment: Use Unicode instead `const wchar_t* Filtros[] = { L"Media", ... };`

Comment: I'm not sure there is a simple solution. You decide for yourself after reading [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/).

Answer (score 4):

ANSI/ASCII text interpreted as Unicode/UTF-16LE [tends to look like Chinese](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140930-00/?p=43953).

You have defined UNICODE in your project settings so `CreateWindow` and `SendMessage` will be Unicode but you are passing in ANSI strings. The compiler cannot catch this because of the C cast.

Use `LPCTSTR Filtros[]` or `const wchar_t* Filtros[]` and `TEXT("...")` or `L"..."` to make your strings Unicode.

You can also make the cast type safe by replacing `(LPARAM)Filtros[i]` with  `(LPARAM)const_cast<LPCTSTR>(Filtros[i])` and the compiler will complain if you pass the wrong string type...

Answer (score 0):

Try this, the type is not const char*, too type is const wchar_t*:

```
const wchar_t* items[] = { L"First item", L"Second item", 
    L"Internet", L"Solaris", L"Arch" };
```

And create a drop down button list with own code:

```
 HWND  hwndCombo = CreateWindowW(L"Combobox", 
                NULL, 
                WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | 
                CBS_DROPDOWNLIST,
                10, 10, 120, 110, hwnd, NULL, g_hinst, NULL);   

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++ )
 {

              SendMessageW(hwndCombo, CB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM) items[i]);
   }
```